# Split string using comma and multi conditions in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

I have complex split issue for MSSQL Query as the below:

```
Dani,george,michael - USA,Uk,CA
```

And I want to get the below output:

[image]

Can anyone give me a hint, if this possible?

Comment: You can't do this without a UDF.  Even `STRING_SPLIT` cannot handle this.

Comment: What is the SQL Server version?

Comment: @Zhorov it;s 2012

Comment: I really suggest fixing your data model...

Comment: Do you have a table with a single column of text in it to start with. It would be good if you could post some code. There's no indication of how many rows you have. You could split the data into 6 columns and then join the resulting data from column 1 to column 4 then do a union to the same thing for columns 2 to 5 etc.

Comment: You want HTML output? There's loads of sql on the web to turn a table into HTML I imagine SO has plenty of suggestions.

Comment: @AndyRobertson No I need the data in table with 2 columns Name and country

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Grab a copy of [`DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2).
2. Put it on your instance, either in the database your (awful) double delimited data is in or in a Utility database.
3. Use the aforementioned function to **fix** your design. For the sample we have:

> ```
> DECLARE @YourDelimitedString varchar(100) = 'Dani,george,michael - USA,Uk,CA';
>
> SELECT MAX(CASE DS1.ItemNumber WHEN 1 THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(DS2.Item)) END) AS [Name],
>        MAX(CASE DS1.ItemNumber WHEN 2 THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(DS2.Item)) END) AS Country
> INTO dbo.NewTable
> FROM (VALUES(@YourDelimitedString))V(DelimitedString)
>      CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD (V.DelimitedString,'-') DS1
>      CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD (DS1.Item,',') DS2
> GROUP BY DS2.ItemNumber;
> ```

5. `DROP` your old table and rename your new table to your old table's name.
6. *(This step is now redundant as the OP has changed their question to not require HTML data)* Now making HTML data is easy peasy:

> ```
> DECLARE @HTML nvarchar(MAX),
>         @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);
>
> SET @HTML = N'<table>' + @CRLF +
>             N'    <tbody>' + @CRLF +
>             N'         <tr>' + @CRLF +
>             N'             <th>Name</th>' + @CRLF +
>             N'             <th>Country></th>' + @CRLF +
>             N'        <tr>' + @CRLF +
>             N'        ' +
>             (SELECT td = [name],'',
>                     td = [Country],''
>              FROM dbo.OldTable
>              FOR XML PATH('tr')) + @CRLF +
>             N'    </tbody>' + @CRLF +
>             N'</table>';
>
> PRINT @HTML;
> ```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a2c3fd509361affb3be41e12a294ba45)

Comment: Thank you, but it let's assume that @YourDelimitedString is a column into table can I reed it instead of VALUES ( @YourDelimitedString)

Comment: See the Fiddle, @Jons , which uses a table. And you *should* be able to easily work out how to replace `(VALUES ( @YourDelimitedString)) V(DelimitedString)` with a table...